# vb write information from SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I use visual basic 2008 and a SQL Server database. I want to write the information stock in the database and I want to be rank like in php I use table to rank information what the method to do that in vb. This code write only last information into the table `tbl_cars`

```
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim sqlconn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\m7md\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Cars\Cars\cars.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")
dt = New DataTable
da = New SqlDataAdapter
Dim sql As String = ("select * from tbl_cars ")
da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlconn)
sqlconn.Open()
da.Fill(dt)
For Each drRow As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Label6.Text= (drRow.Item("db_type").ToString)
    Label7.Text = (drRow.Item("db_gender").ToString)
    Label8.Text = (drRow.Item("db_color").ToString)
    Label9.Text = (drRow.Item("db_price").ToString)

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: it is probably writing all the rows it is just that you overwrite 1 with 2 then 3.... To display like a table, you need a grid, or a panel with a lot of labels.  YOu are using the same label over and over.

Comment: What do you mean by rank? Do you mean sort? Also, you only see the last record because each iteration (for each) overwrites the previous records values in the label so when it is done, you only see the last record.  Try adding a datagrid and setting the datasource to the table (dt).  Then you will see all records.

Comment: Your `for each` loop is updating your labels with each iteration of the loop, probably too fast to see, and finishing with the last row, which is my you see the last row's values. Don't you want to use a data grid instead to display the content of your data table?

Comment: can you translate that to code because im new in vb and i need some help thx